# Should I wait to generate a new world until bukkit updates to 1.7.2?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit

I'm resurrecting my server after many months of crunch time. I haven't updated it since the 1.6.2 patch. I've read that there are many changes to the world generation code; new biomes, larger biomes, and smaller oceans.

I have a seed that I like and I wanted to generate a new world using it. However, I'm not sure if generating it now vs later will change the world that the seed creates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I wait to generate a new world until bukkit updates to 1.7.2?

This is kind of a personal decision.

Now, if your question really is :

> I'm not sure if generating it now vs later will change the world that the seed creates.

It will probably change it yes. 
The seed is not a map itself it's simply a number guiding the computer generating the map because it is not capable of doing real random things.
What will happen is the seed will be the same but it will be applied to the new rules (new biomes, larger biomes) and your world won't be the exactly the same since it is a significant update and that some mechanics are changing.

From the seed page of the minecraft wiki :

> Whenever the world generation algorithm is updated, the same seed will no longer generate the same terrain. This is why in some different versions of the game, the same seed will not give the same world.